# How to set default type converters for a number of OSGi modules

Tags: java, maven, blueprint-osgi

I'm working on a Maven-built codebase with many modules, all of which produce OSGi bundles.  Very many of them have an identical list of custom type converters in their blueprint.xml files, converting String to List, Map, and Array.

What are reasonable strategies for avoiding the repetition of that list?

Comment: Can you give some examples or can you give a pointer where to take a look?

Comment: Examples?  I frankly don't understand why that would make any difference. The blueprint schema has a "type-converters" element, which are used for converting values between types.  Many of the blueprint.xml files in the project duplicate the same short list of converter classes (converting from String to List, Map, and Array). I'm looking for strategies for reducing that duplication.

Comment: Ok. Than no example sorry than it's hard to help...